# How can &deployment satisfy type runtime.Object in kubernetes code?

Tags: pointers, go, methods, interface, kubernetes

In [`kubectl/run.go`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubectl/run.go#L59) in Kubernetes code, the `Generate` function has a result list of these two types:

```
runtime.Object, error
```

The last line of the function is:

```
return &deployment, nil
```

`runtime` is imported:

```
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime
```

I got `runtime` by running `go get` on that import statement, and Object is defined in `interfaces.go`:

```
type Object interface {
    GetObjectKind() schema.ObjectKind
    DeepCopyObject() Object
}
```

(And I found the same code on the web [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/interfaces.go).)

The address operator creates a pointer... more specifically, the Go spec states:

> For an operand x of type T, the address operation &x generates a pointer of type *T to x.

and pointers [have a type distinct from their base type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types):

> A pointer type denotes the set of all pointers to variables of a given type, called the base type of the pointer.

How does `&deployment` satisfy the `runtime.Object` type?

My best guess so far is that `deployment` implements the `runtime.Object` interface, and mapping `&deployment` to `runtime.Object` satisfies [this rule of assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability):

> T is an interface type and x implements T.

and that a return statement mapping to a result list type is equivalent to assignment in this respect.  Is this correct?  If not, is there another part of the specification or documentation that explains it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`deployment` is a local variable, its declaration:

```
deployment := extensionsv1beta1.Deployment{
    // ...
}
```

Where `extensionsv1beta1` from the imports:

```
import (
    // ...
    extensionsv1beta1 "k8s.io/api/extensions/v1beta1"
    // ...
)
```

Doc of [`extensionsv1beta1.Deployment`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/api/extensions/v1beta1#Deployment). Its definition is:

```
type Deployment struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta `json:",inline"`
    // ...other fields...
}
```

It embeds [`metav1.TypeMeta`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#TypeMeta), which has a method [`GetObjectKind()`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#TypeMeta.GetObjectKind) method with pointer receiver. This means a pointer to `Deployment` also has this method, because [Spec: Struct types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)

> Given a struct type `S` and a defined type `T`, promoted methods are included in the method set of the struct as follows:
>
> - If `S` contains an embedded field `T`, the method sets of `S` and `*S` both include promoted methods with receiver `T`. **The method set of `*S` also includes promoted methods with receiver `*T`.**

And `Deployment` has a "direct" [`DeepCopyObject()`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/api/extensions/v1beta1#Deployment.DeepCopyObject) method, again with pointer receiver. So the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of `*Deployment` contains this method.

And last quoting [Spec: Interface types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)

> An interface type specifies a [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) called its *interface*. **A variable of interface type can store a value of any type with a method set that is any superset of the interface.** Such a type is said to *implement the interface*.

So this means the method set of `*Deployment` has all the methods defined by `Object`, or in other words: the method set of `*Deployment` is a superset of the method set of `Object`, so `*Deployment` implements `Object`.

`deployment` is of type `extensionsv1beta1.Deployment`, which means `&deployment` is of type `*extensionsv1beta1.Deployment`, which we showed above that it implements `Object`; so the value `&deployment` can be assigned to or be stored in a variable of type `Object`.

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to assign an `Object` type to `deployment`?