# Golang interface & *interface

Tags: go, go-interface

I am trying to use interfaces more in my codebase for a game server I am writing and understand the high level concept and when one should be used (I think). In my case I am using them to decouple my packages from one another amongst other as well as make testing easier.

My question boils down to I have a struct which has ptr receive methods. I am then passing this struct to another function via an interface just like in this [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wIvbAMsDRFw) I am confused as to why a function with a parameter of type interface can accept an address to something that implements that interface. Why is it not `func something(f *face)`, what purpose does `*interface` serve?

Comment: Related / Possible duplicate of [How can &deployment satisfy type runtime.Object in kubernetes code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861383/how-can-deployment-satisfy-type-runtime-object-in-kubernetes-code/48861656#48861656)

Comment: Rule of thumb: Never use a pointer to an interface. Pointer to interface is allowed because it is useful if a function wants to change the interface _itself_. If you do not understand this: Fine. Just do not use pointer to interface as it is not needed in 99.99% of all cases.

Comment: See my answer here, it annotates why this is a thing and addresses the common confusion surrounding interface pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370277/type-is-pointer-to-interface-not-interface-confusion/44372954#44372954

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the case that "a parameter of type interface can accept an address to something that implements that interface". Quite the opposite.

Your concrete foo does **not** implement the interface face. It doesn't.

Only `*foo` does which is a different type in Go.

You can *only* assign `*foo` to variables of type face. (Okay, there is some sugar in Go which might let you an addressable foo to a face, but here the process of taking the pointer is automatic).

Take a look at the language spec and the type system.

Comment: I read the spec (surrounding types, methods and interface) and I was confused as to why `*foo` implements the interface but `foo` does not.My understanding of `func (receiver) Name(parms) {}` is that it's syntatic sugar for `func Name(receiver,
 parms) {}` and so am confused as to why the ptr to the struct implements it but the concrete does not.

Comment: @John Well because there is no `func Work(foo)` so there is no `func Work(foo)`. It does not matter whether you which format you choose to write down methods. The key to understanding is that `*foo` and `foo` are two totally normal but different types in Go. It is not that `foo` is a real type and *foo is some "take the address mumbo jumbo". *foo is a type like map[string][]complex128 is. *foo can have methods just as map[string][]complex128 can have methods. if *foo doesn't have method Work it cannot be assigned to face.

Comment: thanks I think I understand. I have been treating `*foo` & `foo` the same with `*` being the address of `foo` rather than a completely separate type that just so happens to be a ptr.

Comment: To be fair, there's a lot of syntactical sugar surrounding it.  If your `Work()` method used a `(f foo)` receiver instead of a `(f *foo)` receiver, then you could pass _either_ a `foo` or a `*foo` to the interface.  Method calls work the same way, you can call a pointer-receiver method on a non-pointer variable, as long as its addressable.  The only place this really breaks down is that you cannot use _pointer_ methods to fulfill an interface when passing a _value_ of that type to the interface.  The reverse is not the case, you _can_ use value methods to fulfill for a passed pointer.