# How to use runtime.Object to create CRD generic functions in go

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I'm writing a Kubernetes controller in which I need to run a function over different kinds of resources, including my custom resources and other kinds of resources (This function is only interested in the resource name).

My understanding is that this is doable using `runtime.Object` but I can't get it to work.
Here's the function signature:

```
func myFunc(foo []runtime.Object) []runtime.Object
```

When calling the function I pass a typed object, and expect it to be assignable to `runtime.Object`:

```
foo := []v1alpha1.MyCRD{}
bar := myFunc(foo)
```

I'm getting compiler error:

```
cannot use foo (type []v1alpha1.MyCRD) as []runtime.Object in argument to myFunc
```

Looking at the definition of `runtime.Object`:

```
type Object interface {
  GetObjectKind() schema.ObjectKind
  DeepCopyObject() Object
}
```

The `MyCRD` type is embedding `metav1.TypeMeta` so it has the required `GetObjectKind()` function.

It is also annotated with:

```
// +k8s:deepcopy-gen:interfaces=k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime.Object
```

So it also has the required `DeepCopyObject()` (which is see in the generated file).

I've been struggling with this for a while and I think it might have to do with registering the type with `scheme` but I'm not sure how that works, and can't find any documentation on that. I've tried copying type registration code from other projects I found without really understanding what it does (as I said, can't find docs on this).. still doesn't work.

---

related:

- [How can &deployment satisfy type runtime.Object in kubernetes code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861383/how-can-deployment-satisfy-type-runtime-object-in-kubernetes-code)
- https://medium.com/@arschles/go-experience-report-generics-in-kubernetes-25da87430301